# how to use GXT Charts in my GWT project

Tags: gxt

I am going to use GXT Charts for the first time

I simply get the code from here

```
     http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:columnchart
```

My other GXT widgets are working (have added GXT jar and
 `<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>`)

but This Import is giving error as "undefined"

```
       import com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart;

   Error:   The import com.sencha.gxt.chart cannot be resolved
```

do i have to add some additional jar for CHARTS ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a separate gxt-chart jar in our project

Comment: Specifically gxt-chart-3.0.0.jar

Comment: as i am getting this error  :   No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart<M>; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: do you have "<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart'/>" in your gwt.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Download and add the jar to your project

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gxt/gxt-chart-3.0.1.jar.zip